# What forms are the verbs in "Omnibus rebus paratis, Caesar milites naves conscendere jussit"?

Tags: verbs, gerund, ablative-absolute

In "*Omnibus rebus paratis, Caesar milites naves conscendere jussit*", what forms are the verbs "*paratis*" and "*jussit*", and why?

This sentence was taken from *Gramática latina de Napoleão Mendes*, from the chapter talking about the ***Absolute Ablative*** and ***Ablative Gerund*** (not sure about the names in English). Independent of the case the phrase is related to, the verbs were expected to be in participle form, which doesn't seems to be the case, seeing as the participle form ends in "*-ns*, *-ntis*."

"*Paratis*", as far as I know, is the **2nd person plural present** for the verb ***paro, -are***, and "*jussit*" is the **3rd person singular past perfect** of the verb ***jubeo, -es, jussi, jussum, -ere***.

The translation for the sentence given in the book is:
*Preparadas todas as coisas, César ordenou que os soldados subissem nos navios*. (Pt)
*Prepared everything, Caesar ordered the soldiers to board the ship*. (Partially Google translated)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You were spot on with your parsing of *iussit*; it is, in fact, the *third person singular perfect active indicative* of *iubeō, iubēre, iussī, iussum*.

With regards to *parātīs* (the macrons should give a bit of a spoiler regarding what it is), you were not quite there. It is the *perfect passive participle* of *parō, parāre, parāvī, parātum*, and is being used in an *ablative absolute* expression.

The whole phrase should be translated as such:

> *Omnibus rēbus parātīs, Caesar mīlitēs navēs cōnscendere iussit.*
>
> *With all things (having been) prepared, Caesar ordered the soldiers to board the ships.*

As a bit of a side note, Caesar's commentaries (to the best of my knowledge) are almost exclusively written in the third person; unless something or someone is being quoted, potentially ambiguous forms that look like personal conjugations (1st, 2nd person), like *paratis* (without the macrons, of course), can usually be assumed to not be personal conjugations.